# Processing returned value of SOAP

Tags: php, curl, soap

I am using PHP CURL to initiate a SOAP request.  I do not understand how to process the returned data and the site I am requesting the data from is not helping.  This is my first CURL / SOAP project and am open to suggestions on a different path, if a better one exists.

Following is my code:

```
    $soapUrl = "https://its.emdeon.com/ITS/itsws.asmx";
    $soapUser = $emdeonUserID;  //  username
    $soapPassword = $emdeonPassword; // password
    $msgType = 'X12'; 

    // xml post structure

    $xml_post_string .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
    $xml_post_string .= '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">';
    $xml_post_string .= '<soap12:Body>';
    $xml_post_string .= '<SendRequest xmlns="https://ITSWebService.emdeon.com/">';
    $xml_post_string .= '<sUserID>'.$soapUser.'</sUserID>';
    $xml_post_string .= '<sPassword>'.$soapPassword.'</sPassword>';
    $xml_post_string .= '<sMessageType>'.$msgType.'</sMessageType>';
    $xml_post_string .= '<sEncodedRequest>'.$my270_base64.'</sEncodedRequest>';
    $xml_post_string .= '</SendRequest>';
    $xml_post_string .= '</soap12:Body>';
    $xml_post_string .= '</soap12:Envelope>';   


$url = $soapUrl;


$soap_do = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $xml_post_string); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml_post_string) )); 

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
$err = curl_error($soap_do);




echo "<< result >> ",$result;

echo "<< err >> ",$err;
```

And this is the value of `$result`:

```
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
```

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP's [SOAP client library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)? It's even built-in. I don't see any reason you should do all this XML processing by hand.

Comment: You are probably correct, but not knowing any better, CURL was the first thing I found when searching for a solution.  As it turns our my code is good.  I discovered that the returned data contains a status code in position 1.  When stripped out I can decode the remaining data and I have the result I was looking for.